# ZeroMQ reliability?

Tags: python, zeromq

I've been using ZeroMQ's request/response sockets for the purpose of exchanging messages between a web application and slave applications that were used for offloading processing. I've noticed that in a few cases, not all ZMQ messages sent were actually received by the other side. What's even weirded that this happens even with the **IPC** protocol, which, I thought, would be pretty reliable.

What could be responsible for the sent message not being delivered, while not producing any errors?

*Here is an example of the client code:*

```
# ironic
class ReliableClient(object):
    def _reconnect(self):
        if self.socket:
            self.socket.close()
            self.socket = None

        self.socket = self.context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        self.socket.connect(self.server_url)

        # Give the server 2 sec to respond
        self.socket.RCVTIMEO = 2000
        self.socket.SNDTIMEO = 2000

        self.socket.LINGER = 3

    def __init__(self, server_url=None, server_name=None):
        self.socket = None
        self.server_url = server_url

        if server_name is None:
            self.server_name = server_url
        else:
            self.server_name  = server_name

        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.context = zmq.Context()

        self._reconnect()

    def msg(self, msg):
        raw_out = dumps(msg)

        # send
        self.lock.acquire()
        try:
            self.socket.send(
                raw_out,
                copy=True
            )
        except zmq.ZMQError as ex:
            log.exception(ex, '%s: failed to send', self.server_name)
            self.lock.release()
            raise CommunicationError('failed to send')

        # receive
        try:
            raw_in = self.socket.recv()
        except zmq.ZMQError as ex:
            log.exception(ex, '%s: failed to receive', self.server_name)
            raise CommunicationError('failed to receive')
        finally:
            self.lock.release()

        msg_in = loads(raw_in)  

        return msg_in
```

Comment: I'm not suggesting that this question is off topic. But you really should read at least the first five chapters of [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) before using zmq in any production code. Many reasons can cause you to lose messages in either zmq or BSD socket. Without any details, even the authors of zmq could not find out the reason. HWM is one thing you may want to take a look at

Comment: Are you using `ROUTER` sockets to distribute messages between client/server? If so, I can suggest a technique to identify when a message _cant_ be delivered.

Comment: Dropped or missing messages are sometimes very subtle with respect to their cause; I suggest posting some code snippets so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Can you show server side code? Need to see what the client connects to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the IPC protocol, but I've worked with ZMQ/TCP extensively.

Even the simplest ZMQ REQ/REP pattern over TCP **will never drop messages** if you're using it properly. It may hang indefinitely if your network connection or remote endpoint goes down, but it will never silently fail. There are certain sockets that are by design going to drop messages in certain circumstances. For example, some may drop messages when the HWM is reached.

Answer (score 2):

> What could be responsible for the sent message not being delivered,
>   while not producing any errors?

If you're using `ROUTER` sockets to intermediate messages from server to zmq worker processes, `ROUTER`s, by default, will drop any outbound messages they can't deliver. What does "can't deliver" mean? ROUTERs maintain an internal mapping of client identity to client connection, and because all messages on a router have an identity, either provided by the client or auto-assigned by the router, any outbound message that doesn't have a corresponding connection on which to route, will be dropped, silently.

You can identify when this scenario occurs by telling the ROUTER to report undeliverable messages, in other words, the ROUTER generates an error when it can't deliver a message. In Java, the method is `routerSocket.setRouterMandatory(true)`, you just need to find the python counterpart to this (I'm not a py guy, lol)

If you determine the ROUTER is dropping messages, the question then becomes why? In my case, I had a zmq client that sent and received server messages on different threads, and the receiving thread simply wasn't connecting fast enough for the initial "Ok" response from the server, so it was just a timing issue in the client.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If Two Systems are guarantee to be active all time (24X7) or message should be send only when two Systems are active, ZeroMQ can be used as an excellent way to transfer small events between systems as an excellent options.

We had problem on ZeroMQ pub-sub mode sending large number of messages due to slow subscribers and we started losing message in middle.
Later we moved to ActiveMQ embedded broker mode, which keeps messages in memory until consumer consumes them. Good Thing about ZeroMQ, Subscriber can be started even there is no Publisher or if Publisher will come later into picture.

Limitation of Active MQ, Consumer reading from Queue cannot be started before Producer will create Queue. It will clearly throw exception. We can also use both library and get best of each.